# How can I handle 'Unknown" category in ordinal data analysis?

Tags: r, probability, categorical-data, ordinal-data

I have some environmental monitoring data that I've collected and I'd like to compare the condition plots that have more resources designed to improve their condition "managed" vs. those that haven't "unmanaged".

|  | Managed | Unmanaged |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Very good | 9 | 28 |
| Good | 10 | 50 |
| Fair | 5 | 44 |
| Poor | 3 | 26 |
| Unknown | 1 | 20 |

- Each treatment (managed/unmanaged) has unequal sample sizes
- Each plot was given a condition score of very good, good, fair, poor or unknown (ordinal categorical variable?)
- I'm not sure how to deal with the "unknown" condition.

I thought maybe using the Asymptotic Linear-by-Linear Association Test in R:

```
table <- table(lapply(unstack(data, Condition~Management), factor, 
                  levels=c("Unknown", "Poor", "Fair", "Good", "Very good")))
df <- table(data$Management, data$Condition)
file<-tempfile()
cat("                  \"Condition\"\n", 
"     \"Unknown\"\"Poor\"\"Fair\"\"Good\"\"Very good\n",
"Unmanaged      20  26   44  50         28\n",
"Managed     1  3   5  10       9\n",
file = file)
Tabla <- as.table(read.ftable(file, skip = 2, row.var.names = "Type", col.vars = list("Condition" = c("Unknown", "Poor", "Fair", "Good", "Very good"))))
prop.table(Tabla, margin = 1)
Test = chisq_test(Tabla, scores = list("Condition" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))
Test
```

Should I even include the "Unknowns"? I'm not sure it's appropriate to put them before "Poor". Given I'm analysing the proportion data, excluding the "Unknowns" will substantially change the results.

Comment: Why was the *unknown* value used if all plots where observed and scored? Was the plot destroyed for some unrelated reason, ... ?  Answer must depend onthis information!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen The plots can be quite big and sometimes difficult to access (depending on weather etc.). This would be when "Unknown" is used.